# lost encrytion password

Tags: password

I have forgotten my password to my drive and now when I try to install from the command line.  I cannot get past the password prompt. Can I just start over, reinstall Ubuntu from USB, erase the drive, and reuse the computer with a new Ubuntu install. I know I will lose all data, but that is the cost of stupidity. Fortunately, passwords are backed up on bitwarden.

Comment: Yes, you can reuse your drive. It is probably a good idea when booted into the Ubuntu live system (from USB) to start `gparted` and create a GUID partition table, GPT. Save and exit. Then you can start the installer and let it use the whole drive. And this time write the password/passphrase for the encrypted drive on a paper, and keep that paper in a safe place.

Comment: As an aside... I did a QA-test re-install of a system recently; what is a *upgrade via re-install* or *install using existing partition* which re-installs the system without erasing my data files & automatically re-installs my *manually installed* packages & for some *unknown* reason I couldn't login (*likely my fingers were wrongly positioned!*)... I swore, tried many times to get in, gave up & re-installed again & more carefully entered password & completed QA-test install.  No data files were lost, *manually installed* packages were re-installed as expected & QA install test was passed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can start over with a new installation.

All you need to do is choose the **"Erase disk and install..."** option when choosing the destination for your Ubuntu installation.

In case you need additional reference, here is the official guide to [Install Ubuntu Desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you have older installation media, it's suggested that you create new media to reduce the amount of updates during and after installation.